# YouTube no longer working on production iOS Apps when using iOS6 SDK

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, youtube

A client just called us up and said all their YouTube videos in the App are no longer working.  We haven't touched the App. This must have happened on February 28th, 2014.  We had compiled this for compatibility mode so using iOS6 SDK when we submitted it in December, 2013.  Now we can't see any YouTube working in the Simulator either.  It's just crazy that YouTube and Google would pull the plug on people like this.  We think that we have it working when using the iOS7 SDK but on devices only (simulator still doesn't work) so now we have to port the app to iOS7 only.

Is anyone else having this crisis?